# The 'no versioning' is back for modern sites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, versioning

In my tenancy I can still see the 'no versioning' option in modern sites. The option is missing from sites created from the central admin.

This tenancy did not opt out from the deployment of removing 'no versioning' of september 2018.

Is someone experiencing the same?
[image]

Comment: To understand your issue, please provide some screenshots about "no versioning"

Comment: done //////////////

Answer (score 0):

The update only affects the versioning settings on all OneDrive for Business and SharePoint Online **team site** document libraries, including both group-connected team sites and team sites not connected to an Office 365 Group.

For **Communication sites**, they still use the old settings and "No Versioning" still appears.

More information, you can refer to [New Updates to OneDrive and SharePoint Team Site Versioning](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-OneDrive-Blog/New-Updates-to-OneDrive-and-SharePoint-Team-Site-Versioning/ba-p/204390).